# Java interface like Predicate, but without an argument

Tags: java, predicate, functional-interface

I'm looking for a preexisting functional interface like `Predicate`, but one whose `test` method takes no arguments.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're looking for `BooleanSupplier`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BooleanSupplier.html

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer  to the "unclear" question

Comment: But BooleanSupplier  is missing all the utility methods like "and", "negate" and "or" :(